# Synonym dictionary

Tags: resources

Is there a good synonym dictionary of Russian words like [The Penguin guide to synonyms and related word by S. I. Hayakawa](http://books.google.ru/books?id=wzEjAQAAIAAJ&q=Modern+guide+to+synonyms+and+related+words&dq=Modern+guide+to+synonyms+and+related+words&source=bl&ots=l6UKVwNqeu&sig=ZloDbvSo_jrLEUT13np2xhik5LQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=r8AJUOOYJqHZmAWE_LifCg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA) (which is for English words)?

Because though ordinary defining dictionaries give explanations of the meaning of the words, the difference is not always clear from those definitions. A synonym dictionary would be a great tool to show the differences between words.

---

One example from "The Penguin guide to synonyms and related word"  to illustrate what kind of dictionary I mean:
[image]

Comment: There's probably no such dictionary for Russian synonyms. There are several synonym dictionaries but all of them more or less just enumerate the related words, without explaining their difference.

Comment: @n.m. It's a pity :( I'm a native Russian would benefit from it greatly, let alone those who study Russian as a foreign language.

Answer (score 5):

I am aware of one dictionary with the structure similar to the one requested.  It's *Новый объяснительный словарь синонимов русского языка*.  It doesn't contain a large number of synonyms, however it does a pretty good job explaining the differences within a set of synonyms.

As I have found it on the internet myself, I am sharing it via my web site.  However please note that I will remove it if requested so by copyright owners. [Here is the link](http://shchuka.com/hosting/russian_synonyms.pdf).

Comment: This dictionary seem to be for linguist and not for ordinary learners not acquainted with the terminology. At least, at first glance it seemed a bit overcomplicated for me. While "The Penguin guide to synonyms and related word" gives a simple explanation in everyday language of the word differences, suitable for ordinary people.

Comment: @ovgolovin You are probably right.  It's not on the same level as the Penguin's one.  Yet it's the only one I found that actually provides more than just sets of words.